# SQL Server - Replacing NULL values with mode of column grouped by another column

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a table (call it `oldtable`) and the relevant columns are `name`, `group`, `zip code`. I have selected those into a new table (call that `newtable`). My issue is that some of the zip codes in the first table are NULL. I want to replace the NULL zip codes with the mode (most common value) of their `group`.

For example, say a row in `newtable` looks like this:

```
Name   Group ZipCode
Blah   G1    NULL
```

I want to replace that NULL with the most common zip code over all the people in G1 in `oldtable`. I am having trouble even getting started on pulling the mode of one column when grouped by another column.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I know this kind of question is gauche, but... are you _sure_ you want to just fill in empty values like that?

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem...

Comment: @Andy yes, this is for a specific business use case. Matching the wrong value won't result in a different outcome than keeping them NULL.

Comment: @scsimon I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @drj3122 down the line will you ever need to know which correctly have the value and which had the value assigned because it was blank?

Comment: @Andy In this case, no we won't. If something changes, I can add a flag in the future to indicate which was a NULL originally.

Comment: @Andy I decided to be responsible and keep the original column intact and update a separate column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using CROSS APPLY on an UPDATE.

```
UPDATE n SET
    zipcode = x.zipcode
FROM newtable n
CROSS APPLY( SELECT TOP 1 zipcode, COUNT(*) cnt
            FROM newtable o
            WHERE n.[group] = o.[group]
            GROUP BY zipcode
            ORDER BY cnt DESC) x
WHERE n.zipcode IS NULL;
```

Comment: I think `newtable` within the cross apply should be `oldtable`.
Otherwise, is this understanding correct: The cross apply goes through each row in newtable where zipcode is null, then uses the mode zipcode from oldtable where the name and group match. If so, I think I want to remove the name criteria. I want the mode for each group over all names within that group. Most names will only appear once.

Comment: You're right, I missed the part where you mentioned that the mode is per group. I've edited the code to reflect that. The newtable and oldtable could both be used if they contain the same information.